# Making a dynamic variable set

Tags: python

I'm trying to put together a tool that has a notion of 'level'. 
Each 'level' has a set of variables that are needed to support the activity I want to achieve that are specific to each level.

I have written a hard-coded version that works (to a degree) but it is limited to the number of levels I have hard-coded. It strikes me that there must be a slicker way of writing this func so can generate the level vars on the fly:

```
def levelVarsGetter(level):
    if level == 1:
        levelDict = {'URLRegEx':baseDict['L1Regex'], 'titleRegEx':baseDict['L1TitleRegex'], 'buildPortion':baseDict['L1buildPortion'], 'levelParser':'level_1'}
    elif level ==2:
        levelDict = {'URLRegEx':baseDict['L2Regex'], 'titleRegEx':baseDict['L2TitleRegex'], 'buildPortion':baseDict['L2buildPortion'], 'levelParser':'level_2'}
    elif level ==3:
        levelDict = {'URLRegEx':baseDict['L3Regex'], 'titleRegEx':baseDict['L3TitleRegex'], 'buildPortion':baseDict['L3buildPortion'], 'levelParser':'level_3'}
    elif level ==4:
        levelDict = {'URLRegEx':baseDict['L4Regex'], 'titleRegEx':baseDict['L4TitleRegex'], 'buildPortion':baseDict['L4buildPortion'], 'levelParser':'level_4'}
    elif level ==5:
        levelDict = {'URLRegEx':baseDict['L5Regex'], 'titleRegEx':baseDict['L5TitleRegex'], 'buildPortion':baseDict['L5buildPortion'], 'levelParser':'level_5'}
    return levelDict
```

All the vars in the dict are manually entered in an initialisation func. There labels can be changed if required.

for context, the referring code:

```
for x in xrange (1, baseDict['numberOfLevels']+1):
    links=[]
    levelDict= levelVarsGetter(x)
    URLRegEx = levelDict['URLRegEx'] 
    titleRegEx = levelDict['titleRegEx']
    buildPortion = levelDict['buildPortion']
    level = levelDict['levelParser'] 
    go = siteParser()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just do:

```
def levelVarsGetter(l):
    return {'URLRegEx': baseDict['L%dRegex' % l],
            'titleRegEx': baseDict['L%dTitleRegex' % l],
            'buildPortion': baseDict['L%dbuildPortion' % l],
            'levelParser': 'level_%d' % l}
```

However, I suspect your data structure should be designed differently. Whatever is stored in `baseDict` could instead be stored in a dictionary that is first keyed by level, then by type, like

```
{1: {"Regex": ..., "TitleRegex": ..., "buildPortion": ...},
 2: {"Regex": ..., "TitleRegex": ..., "buildPortion": ...}...
```

If your levels are sequential (doesn't skip numbers), you should keep them as a list:

```
levels = [{"Regex": ..., "TitleRegex": ..., "buildPortion": ...},
          {"Regex": ..., "TitleRegex": ..., "buildPortion": ...}...
```

(though note that you'd have to access it as `levels[0]` to get level 1).

Indeed, it's likely the the best design is to have a class called `Level` that has attributes `regex`, `title_regex`, and so on. This would let the `Level` class also contain methods for common tasks. For example:

```
class Level:
    def __init__(self, url_regex, title_regex, build_portion):
        self.url_regex = url_regex
        self.title_regex = title_regex
        self.build_portion = build_portion

    def method1(self):
        """use build_portion to do something"""
        self.build_portion.do_something()

    def method2(self):
        """use title_regex and url_regex to do something else"""
        x = self.title_regex + self.url_regex 
        x.do_something_else()
```

Comment: Unless he's going to have dozens or hundreds of dynamically entered and randomly accessed levels, or his level numbers need to be non-sequential, it seems like a list or even tuple is a better structure for the outer enclosure than a dict.

Comment: @sr2222: I agree, except that I wasn't sure it would be sequential. (Even if the items are randomly accessed a list is still better).

Comment: Plus then you aren't building a whole new dict every time you access level data for the same level.

Comment: My levels are sequential, so the list structure seems to be a good fit. I'm unsure how I would access each data element - my logic for having a set that is dynamically created is that I can refer to a single instance of a var (e.g. `URLRegEx`) and the func that uses it doesn't care what level its on. I'm unclear how to surface the level vars as a block to give back to the core code.

Comment: @JayGattuso: It's clear to me that you should be making `Level` a class, and put your code that "doesn't care what level it is on" as a method in that class, using `self.URLRegEx` when it wants to refer to that level's regex (see my example above). This is the kind of problem that object-oriented programming was meant to solve.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I agree - I'm just not very good at working out to implement this kind of stuff! all this commentary is very useful to me as I figure out how to put this stuff together better. Thank you for you time, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just put this in a list, and use the list indeces as your level numbers?  Ex:

```
levels = [{'URLRegEx' : 'l1url', 'titleRegEx' : 'l1title', 'buildPortion' : 'l1build'},
          {'URLRegEx' : 'l2url', 'titleRegEx' : 'l2title', 'buildPortion' : 'l2build'},
          ...]
```

Comment: I could do, but that would still result in a hard coded set, not a dynamic one?

Comment: Indeed, but the point was to get way from the hard-coded version and create a dynamic one that scales to n levels.

Comment: You need to record the data somewhere.  Both dicts and lists are mutable, so you can add to or modify any of the level data at any time during program execution.  If you need added functionality, you should go with a list of objects as @DavidRobinson suggests, but if all you need is some dictionaries stored in a certain order, there's no good reason to overcomplicate things with objects and/or interpolator and filter methods.